# Can't find how to compile a custom MIB to use in my simple python SNMP-Tool

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, mib

I'm trying to compile a custom MIB (which I need to get Information from a Qnap NAS) to use it in my pysnmp program.
I tried compiling it manually, but it seems like `mibdump.py` tries to get a MIB from  `http://mibs.snmplabs.com/pysnmp/notexts/@mib@` and ignores the MIB that I give.
I tried compiling it in these two ways but nothing worked. 
`mibdump.py --destination-directory=C:/Users/me/Desktop --destination-format=pysnmp C:/Users/me/Desktop/NAS`
`mibdump.py --generate-mib-texts --destination-directory=C:/Users/me/Desktop --destination-format=pysnmp C:/Users/me/Desktop/NAS`
In both cases the following was printed and the only thing resulting was a NAS.py-file which basically contained the Google "search" page html-code.

```
Borrow missing/failed MIBs from: http://mibs.snmplabs.com/pysnmp/fulltexts/@mib@
Existing/compiled MIB locations: pysnmp.smi.mibs, pysnmp_mibs
Compiled MIBs destination directory: C:/Users/me/Desktop
MIBs excluded from code generation: INET-ADDRESS-MIB, PYSNMP-USM-MIB, RFC-1212, RFC-1215, RFC1065-SMI, RFC1155-SMI, RFC1158-MIB, RFC1213-MIB, SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB, SNMP-TARGET-MIB, SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC, SNMPv2-TM, TRANSP
ORT-ADDRESS-MIB
MIBs to compile: NAS
Destination format: pysnmp
Parser grammar cache directory: not used
Also compile all relevant MIBs: yes
Rebuild MIBs regardless of age: no
Dry run mode: no
Create/update MIBs: yes
Byte-compile Python modules: yes (optimization level no)
Ignore compilation errors: no
Generate OID->MIB index: no
Generate texts in MIBs: yes
Keep original texts layout: no
Try various file names while searching for MIB module: yes
Created/updated MIBs:
Pre-compiled MIBs borrowed: NAS (http://mibs.snmplabs.com:80/pysnmp/fulltexts/NAS.py)
Up to date MIBs:
Missing source MIBs:
Ignored MIBs:
Failed MIBs:
```

IF it can help, this is the function which will then use my MIB. I'm pretty sure that the function isn't a problem, because loading the HOST-RESOURCES-MIB (with pysnmp-mibs installed) doesn't give any problem at all:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

def get(ip_address, mib, mibpath, oid):

    iterator = getCmd(SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget((ip_address, 161)),
                      ContextData(),
                      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(mib, oid, 0).addAsn1MibSource('file:///usr/share/snmp', mibpath)))
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator)
    if errorIndication:  # SNMP engine errors
        print(errorIndication)
    else:
        if errorStatus:  # SNMP agent errors
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(), varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1] if errorIndex else '?'))
        else:
            for varBind in varBinds:  # SNMP response contents
                return oid + ': ' + str(varBind[1])
```

Am I doing something wrong compiling the file? Is there another method to do this?